# Rails 7: local (non-XHR) request with a form_with form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, ruby-on-rails-7, form-with

In Rails 7 a form generated with `form_with` tag sends remote request by default (turbo.js handles form submit event instead, whatever).

Previously one would pass `remote: false` or `local: true` parameters to form helper, to get just a regular HTML form behavior.

But not anymore, this doesn't work:

```
<%= form_with scope: :session, url: session_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <p><%= form.label :email %></p>
  <p><%= form.text_field :email %></p>

  <p class="mt"><%= form.label :password %></p>
  <p><%= form.password_field :password %></p>

  <p class="mt"><%= form.submit "Enter" %></p>
<% end %>
```

What option should I pass to form_with helper in order to get a non-XHR request from my form?

Answer (score 10):

You actualy need to pass a `data: {turbo: false}` to make form send a regular request:

```
<%= form_with scope: :session, url: session_path, data: {turbo: false} do |form| %>
  <p><%= form.label :email %></p>
  <p><%= form.text_field :email %></p>

  <p class="mt"><%= form.label :password %></p>
  <p><%= form.password_field :password %></p>

  <p class="mt"><%= form.submit "Enter" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I wouldn't be suprised if this is or will become a "first- class" option (Like with Rails UJS) so you can just write `form_with ...,
 turbo: false` instead of explicitly setting it as a data attribute.

Comment: Agreed! For now on (rails 7.0.1) you can't use it like this. I've checked it twice.

Comment: @installero how did you find that? I did not see in the `form_with` documentation